# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ) for custom theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/advanced-wordpress-comment-styles-and-tricks/)  and I can't manage to get my Reply working as intended with the `wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );` php function.

- [functions.php PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dJR6f6t9)
- [header.php PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/dJR6f6t9)
- [single.php PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/RfEZ0ELQ)
- [comments.php PasteBin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120818030030/http://pastebin.com:80/4N3rfsJY)
- footer:
  `</body>
  </html>
  <!-- Footer Sections -->`

I've removed code which I think is irrelevant for what I wish to accomplish.

**Expected Output (Taken from Twenty Eleven 1.3 *Minus stylesheets*)**

[image: Expected output]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/n3cvsots.tjn.png))</sub>

**Actual Output (Taken from my theme *Minus stylesheets*)**

[image: Actual output]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/w3x4u4q0.3w4.png))</sub>

How can I accomplish the **Expected Output** based off this [tutorial](https://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/advanced-wordpress-comment-styles-and-tricks/) for Advanced Comments? and what should I be doing with my functions.php and single.php to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is actually pretty simple... after a little of reading the wordpress code for the javascript. I found the problem was in how each comment block was created.

based off this function in function.php

```
//this function will be called in the next section
function advanced_comment($comment, $args, $depth) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; 
$PostAuthor = false;
if($comment->comment_author_email == get_the_author_email()) {
$PostAuthor = true;}
elseif($comment->comment_author_email == 'mordauk@gmail.com') {
$PostAuthor = true;} ?>
<li <?php if($PostAuthor) {echo "class='authorcomment' ";} ?>
<?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
<div class="comment-author vcard">
<?php echo get_avatar($comment, $size='48',$default='<path_to_url>' ); ?>
<div class="comment-meta"<a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url'); ?>"><?php printf(__('%s'), get_comment_author_link()) ?></a></div>
<small><?php printf(__('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','') ?></small>
</div>
<?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
<div id="moderation"><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></div>
          <?php endif; ?><br />
        <div class="comment-text">  
          <?php comment_text() ?>
        </div>
          <div class="reply">
             <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'])), $comment->comment_ID) ?>
             <?php delete_comment_link(get_comment_ID()); ?>
          </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
      <?php } ?>
```

I found the error was with

```
<?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
```

By simply removing the "li-" in the id so it forms id="comment-"

The reply form now moves on reply.

Comment: This is it: By simply removing the "li-" in the id so it forms id="comment-"